# Asynctask ArrayList object not passing from doInBackground to onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, closures

I have an `AsyncTask` that takes in context (used `onPostExecute`) and runs `doInBackground` to return an ArrayList of objects from a server. When I execute this I can see that `doInBackground` runs fine, however it is not passing the result on to `onPostExecute`.

After much searching, I have yet to find an answer of how to return an ArrayList of objects in an `AsyncTask`.

This is the object I'm creating in `doInBackground` and using `onPostExecute`:

```
public class ServerTimeCard {

    public String eventNameInput;
    Boolean isLocation, isImage, isVoice;

    public ServerTimeCard(String eventNameInput, boolean isLocation, boolean isImage, boolean isVoice) {
        this.eventNameInput = eventNameInput;
        this.isLocation = isLocation;
        this.isImage = isImage;
        this.isVoice = isVoice;
    }

}
```

I'm executing the `AsyncTask` with `new LoadFriendCards(context).execute();` in `onCreate`.

- **Expected Output:** `doInBackground` should return an ArrayList to `onPostExecute`
- **Current Output**: The `ArrayList<ServerTimeCard>` in `onPostExecute` has a size of zero when the same arraylist in `doInBackground` has a larger size.

The following is the `AsyncTask` code.

```
public class LoadFriendCards extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ServerTimeCard>> {

            Context context;
            ArrayList<ServerTimeCard> result;

            public LoadFriendCards(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<ServerTimeCard> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                     result = new ArrayList<ServerTimeCard>();

                     // ...a bunch of data retrieval goes on here...    

                     // querying parse for object info
                     // adding a new object to the local ArrayList for all in db
                     for (String friend : friendsListNames) {
                          ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");
                          query.whereEqualTo("accountName", friend+"@gmail.com");
                          query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                          public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                          if (e == null) {

                               for (ParseObject cardInfo : objects) {

                                   ServerTimeCard item = new ServerTimeCard(
                                      cardInfo.getString("eventName"),
                                      cardInfo.getBoolean("isImage"),
                                      cardInfo.getBoolean("isImage"),
                                      cardInfo.getBoolean("isVoice"));

                                   result.add(item);


                        Log.e("New item called: ", String.valueOf(item.eventNameInput));
                        Log.e("New size of array...", String.valueOf(result.size()));

                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d("info", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
    }

                // returning the new ArrayList<ServerTimeCard> to onPostExecute

                // PROBLEM: THE SIZE OF THE RESULT IS 0
                Log.e("Size of passing array", String.valueOf(result.size()));

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ServerTimeCard> result) {

                // PROBLEM: This returns 0
                Log.e("Data list size: ", String.valueOf(result.size())); 

                // trying to use all objects in the arraylist here but it doesn't work
                // due to the size. Something isn't passing correctly.

            }
        }
```

**Logcat output of Log.e:** (which looks like it calls doInBackground, then onPostExecute, then doInBackground again)

```
E/Size of passing array﹕ 0
E/Data list size:﹕ 0
E/New item called:﹕ yah
E/New size of array...﹕ 1
E/New item called:﹕ lplokolol
E/New size of array...﹕ 2
E/New item called:﹕ It works
E/New size of array...﹕ 3
```

**SOLVED:** I originally thought I needed the AsyncTask but I ended up deleting it all and throwing all the code into a method in my Main class. I was running too many things at once in an asynctask and the structure was throwing data all over the place. Lesson learned: keep it simple.

Comment: Can you show the actual loop? It seems as if you're creating a new list each iteration, but without the loop it's impossible to tell.

Comment: what is the output if you put your log statement just before the `return result` in the doInBackground method?

Comment: @zmbq added the for loop. I'm querying Parse for objects and adding them to the arraylist.

Comment: @donfuxx It outputs `cardInfo.getString("eventName);` perfectly for all objects added to the arraylist.

Comment: To the person that made an edit to my post and ruined the format: I noticed that the AsyncTask constructor doesn't like the {code} format tool and made it work before the edit.

Comment: It was broken before (for me anyway), and it's still broken. Sorry about that. I think it's the bullet list that is messing it up.

Comment: But to help you address your problem -- why would you have an member variable `result`, which you then allocate in `doInBackground()` and pass to `onPostExecute`? At the very least, you'd have potential for a scope conflict, as you're using the same name. You could prefix `result` as `this.result` in `onPostExecute()`, or better yet, get rid of the member variable, and declare and allocate `result` in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: @323go you're right about the formatting- I moved a normal text block between the bulleted list and the {code} and the format is fixed now.

Comment: What about this.result in onPostExecute? Is it empty as well?

Comment: Glad we got that formatting issue worked out; again, sorry for the mess. Try logging `this.result.size()` in `onPostExecute()` and see if the scope issue ate your data.

Comment: I changed the variable names to prevent the name collision scope issue but I still have the same issue (regardless, good catch). **Correction: the passing array in `doInBackground` has a size of zero** That's the issue right there.

Comment: But what is the size of your data member?

Comment: I put `Log.e("Size of passing array", String.valueOf(result.size()));` before result and it says the size is 0. Now the problem becomes: why aren't the items being added correctly?

Comment: `I'm executing the AsyncTask with new LoadFriendCards(context).execute(); in onCreate.` (listed in question)

Comment: Ok, you got me confused pretty well now. There's a `passing` array you pass in, which obviously you don't use. That would be populated with any `ArrayList` you pass to `execute()`. Could you extend the source above to show the various logs and add comments for output?

Comment: When you place a breakpoint in doInBackground, when does result reset itself?

Comment: Also, add logs right after `result.add(item);` to be sure that `item != null` and see `result.size()` immediately after adding.

Comment: Sorry for the mixup, still working on editing to make it more clear... I hope my formatting helps. It appears that it adds the item to the array successfully, however it then resets the array. I've added the complete for loop, which I first omitted to save some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using [findInBackground](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground%28com.parse.FindCallback%29) for your query. That method is done in a background thread. So you're basically running an async task, within an async task.

1. `doInBackground`
2. `findInBackground` -> run asynchronously so code execute continues
3. `onPostExecute` is called before your query finishes.
4. The `done` call back is then called for your query to fill your list

So what you need to do instead is either use `findInBackground` outside of an `AsyncTask` (that method is intended to not be used in an AsyncTask) or use the [find](http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#find%28%29) function.

Answer (score 1):

You're modifying `result` in an anonymous inner class. Your code there doesn't see the result you think it sees, but rather a closure. This is the root of the problem.

Comment: I see- by using that ParseObject Query method (to fetch the data) I'm adding to the array which is later destroyed (for some unknown reason). I'm in the process of googling what a closure is to understand it :). Is there any work around to this?

Answer (score 0):

You are starting a background thread (your async task), and here you call `query.findInBackground()` multiple times which starts MORE background threads. This, however, isn't a problem.

You're getting problems because the AsyncTask is done before all the other threads it started have finished. You only know the other threads are done when each of  their `FindCallback`'s done() method is called.

If you want to know the correct size, you need to code it in a way so that you check the size in the last `done()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to make doInBackground to return an arraylist which can be used in onPostExecute. Just return "ok" or "error". Declare and create a private arraylist as member of your ask. Then fill it in doInBackground and use it in onPostexecute.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative and simpler way is to declare your doInBackground as List type.
Here is my Example

```
    @Override
    protected  ArrayList<ServerTimeCard > doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // Perform the HTTP request for earthquake data and process the response.
        ArrayList<ServerTimeCard > result = QueryUtils.fetchTheData(urls[0]);
        return result;
    }
```